# Order of an automorphism of cyclic $2$-group

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=\langle x\rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $2^n$. The well known things about $Aut(G)$  are

- Any automorphism of $G$ is of the form $x\mapsto x^{i}$ with $i=0,1,\cdots, 2^n-1$ and $(i,2)=1$.
- $Aut(G)\cong C_2\times C_{2^{n-2}}$ ($n\geq 2$)
- The auomotphism $x\mapsto x^5=x^{1+2^2}$ is an automorphism of order $2^{n-2}$.

The problem I am considering is the following:

*Given $i$ with above specified values, is there a simple way to determine the **order of automorphism** $x\mapsto x^i$? If it is difficult for general $i$, then is it easier for special values of $i$ namely*
$$i=1+2, 1+2^2, 1+2^3, \cdots?$$

Comment: It depends what you mean by simple. You just want the smallest $k$ such that $i^{2^k} \equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$, so you just keep squaring $i$ mod $2^n$ unitl you hit $1$, which will be after at most $2^{n-2}$ steps. That seems simple to me, at least in terms of complexity of the algorithm. For special values like $i=1+2^k$ you might be able to calcualte the order exactly. This is probably $2^{n-k}$ when $k \ge 2$.